# Extended inline assembly gcc - Calculating Quadratic Formula roots

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm writing a program using gcc extended inline assembly code to write a program that calculates one of the quadratic roots (from the quadratic formula).  I've written all of my code, and I keep encountering the following error:

"invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter"

I get this error 7 times when I try to compile my program.  My main question is: what does this mean, and why is it happening?  This is a homework assignment, so I'm not asking for a solution per se, but I just can't figure out what that error message means in terms of what parts of my code it applies to (the variables, I'm thinking right now?)

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <math.h>


// function for checking that your assembly code is computing the correct result


double quadraticRootC(double a, double b, double c)

{

        return (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);

}


double quadraticRoot(double a, double b, double c)

{

// write assembly code below to calculate the quadratic root

        double root;

        asm(
                "fld        %a              \n"
                "fadd       %%ST            \n"
                "fld        %a              \n"
                "fld        %c              \n"
                "fmulp      %%ST(1)         \n"
                "fadd       %%ST            \n"
                "fadd       %%ST            \n"
                "fchs                       \n"
                "fld        %b              \n"
                "fld        %b              \n"
                "fmulp      %%ST(1)         \n"
                "faddp      %%ST(1)         \n"
                "ftst                       \n"
                "fstsw      %%AX            \n"
                "sahf                       \n"
                "fsqrt                      \n"
                "fld        %b              \n"
                "fchs                       \n"
                "fdivp      %%ST(1)         \n"
                "mov        %root, %%eax    \n"
                "fstp       %%qword, %%eax  \n"
                "mov        $1, %%eax       \n"
                "jmp        short done      \n"
                "done:                      \n"
                :"=g"(root)
                :"g"(a), "g"(b), "g"(c)
                :"eax"
            );
        return(root);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double  a, b, c;
    double  root, rootC;

    printf("CS201 - Assignment 2p - Hayley Howard\n");  // print your own name instead
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("need 3 arguments: a, b, c\n");
        return -1;
    }
    a = atof(argv[1]);
    b = atof(argv[2]);
    c = atof(argv[3]);
    root = quadraticRoot(a, b, c);
    rootC = quadraticRootC(a, b, c);

    printf("quadraticRoot(%.3f, %.3f, %.3f) = %.3f, %.3f\n", a, b, c, root, rootC);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use operand numbers, not names in your inline assembler. Just replace `%root` with `%0`, `%a` with `%1`, `%b` with `%2` etc.

Look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use symbolic names in inline asm, you need to re-defined them in your constraints:

```
: [root] "=g"(root)
: [a] "g"(a), [b] "g"(b), [c] "g"(c)
```

Then to reference them in your code, you would use %[root], %[a], etc.  Speaking for myself, I find names much easier to read than %0, %1, etc.  Also, during development/testing you may add/remove parameters, which would force you to re-work all your operands in the asm, which is a real pain.

See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#OutputOperands) for more details.